# AWS RDS for MySQL と Google Cloud SQL 間でのデータ連携や移行は可能か？

Tags: mysql, aws

AWSのRDS for MySQL（MariaDB）とGCPのCloud SQLのデータ連携や移行は可能でしょうか？

AWSのRDS for MySLからGCPのCloud SQL for MySQLへのデータ移行の方法は、Export、Importでテーブルの移行、ユーザーや権限、View等移行に問題はないでしょうか。
また、可能な場合に注意事項や制限はありますでしょうか。

方法や注意事項など教えていただけますとありがたいです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0):

使った事は無く少し検索した程度ですが、以下のCloud SQL のドキュメントには次のような記載があります。

[データのインポートとエクスポートのベスト プラクティス | Cloud SQL for MySQL | Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/import-export?hl=ja)

> サポートされているデータベース サーバー（オンプレミス、AWS または Google Cloud）からデータベース全体を新しい Cloud SQL インスタンスに移行する場合は、ファイルのエクスポートとインポートではなく、[Database Migration Service](https://cloud.google.com/database-migration/docs?hl=ja) を使用します。